# Is it ok to add routes in an Express middleware?

Tags: express, basic-authentication

I am building a small authentication middleware (because I want to!) but to work the way I wanted I found I was adding routes dynamically to the app, both for the POST back of the username/password as well as the GET for the authentication page script and styles.

Here it is:

```js
function appAuth(auth, options) {
   let oneHourMs = (60 * 60 * 1000);
   let sessionStore = {};
   let html = `<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`;
    return function (request, response, next) {
        if (!request.app.authMiddlewarePOST_setup) {

            request.app.post(request.path, upload.array(), async function (req, res) {
                let data = req.body;
                console.log("data", data);
                let { username, password } = data;
                if (auth(username, password)) {
                    let now = new Date();
                    let sessionId = await makeSessionId(now, getRemoteAddr(req));
                    sessionStore[sessionId] = {
                        lastTouch: now,
                        id: sessionId
                    };
                    res.cookie("sessionid", sessionId);
                    res.redirect(302, req,path);
                }
                else {
                    res.status(401).send(html);
                }
            });

            request.app.authMiddlewarePOST_setup = true;
        }

        // Do authenticated session detection
        let sessionId = request.cookies.sessionid;
        if (sessionId === undefined) {
            response.status(401).send(html);
            return;
        }

        let sessionObject = sessionStore[sessionId];
        if (sessionObject === undefined
            || isExpired(sessionObject.lastTouch, oneHourMs)) {
            response.status(401).send(html);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise it's all ok.
        next();
    };
}
```

I was wondering:

- is it ok to add routes like this?
- is it better to add a route with an obfuscated path? for example:

```js
 app.post("/" + middlewareId + "/" + randomnumber, ...)
```

- if I'm doing this I suppose I should dispose of the route as well?
- what would be some alternatives to doing this?

The git repo is over [here](https://github.com/nicferrier/express-simpleauth) - I don't want to clutter up the post with even more superflous code.